# SQL - query to get Avg of a Sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

**Question:**
How can I get `avg` of `Sum(od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity)`

The query:

```
SELECT 
    YEAR(o.OrderDate) as [Sales Year],
    MONTH(o.OrderDate) as [Sales Month],
    SUM(CASE WHEN c.catid = 1 THEN od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS [Dispenser Sales],
    SUM(CASE WHEN c.catid = 2 THEN od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity ELSE 0 END) AS [Refill Sales]
FROM 
    Orders o
JOIN
    orderdetails od ON o.order_id = od.orderid
JOIN 
    store s ON s.pro_id = od.Proid
JOIN
    category c ON c.catid = s.catid
GROUP BY 
    YEAR(o.OrderDate), MONTH(o.OrderDate)
ORDER BY 
    YEAR(o.OrderDate), MONTH(o.OrderDate)
```

Comment: use `avg` instead of `sum` in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use `avg()`, but presumably you don't want the missing values to be 0.  So, leave out the `else` clause or be really verbose and use `else NULL`:

```
SELECT YEAR(o.OrderDate) as [Sales Year],
       MONTH(o.OrderDate) as [Sales Month],
       AVG(case when c.catid = 1 then od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity end) AS [Dispenser Sales],
       AVG(case when c.catid = 2 then od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity end) AS [Refill Sales]
FROM . . .
```

Another possibility is that you want the *overall* average.  If so, you can use window functions to append the average to each row.  A subquery/CTE makes this easier:

```
SELECT t.*,
       AVG(DispenserSales) OVER () as avg_DispenserSales,
       AVG(RefillSales) OVER () as avg_RefillSales
FROM (SELECT YEAR(o.OrderDate) as SalesYear,
             MONTH(o.OrderDate) as SalesMonth,
             SUM(case when c.catid = 1 then od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity end) AS DispenserSales,
             SUM(case when c.catid = 2 then od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity end) AS RefillSales
      FROM . . .
     ) t
```

Answer (score 0):

Use avg(od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity) instead of Sum(od.UnitPrice * od.Quantity)

Comment: But you need the average pr. what? Year-month or...?